# How to pass the id of one class object to another class object in django views.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

This is for a library management web app, I need to filter a specific book object by it's id from a BookIssue object and make it as ISSUED when I click on issue button.

Here `Post` model have details of book and `BookIssue` have details of Library Member to borrow book. 
When I click on Issue in html, it will go class `BookIssueView`, from`views.py` I need to change the value of `issued` field of `Post` model to `True`

See `post = Post.objects.filter(id=self.request.GET.get('id')).update(issued=True)` in `views.py` 
Here I need to get the specific book that I selected by it's id. 
How can I implement it?

`models.py`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book_author = models.CharField(default="",max_length=100)
    publisher = models.CharField(default="",max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    issued = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    issued_to = models.CharField(default="",max_length=100,null=False)
    issue_to_phone_number = models.CharField(default="",max_length=10)


    def __str__(self):
        return [self.title,self.id]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk' : self.pk})


class BookIssue(models.Model):
    issue_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    issue_email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    issue_phone_number = models.CharField(default="",max_length=10)
    issue_address = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    issued_book = models.ManyToManyField(Post,default="")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.issue_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-home')
```

`views.py`

```
class BookIssueView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView,Post):
    model = BookIssue
    fields = ['issue_name','issue_email','issue_phone_number','issue_address']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = Post.objects.filter(id=self.request.GET.get('id')).update(issued=True)
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Template

`bookissue_form.html`

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="content-section">

    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Issue Book</legend>
        {{ form|crispy }}
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="button">Issue</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="button">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import (PostListView,
                    PostDetailView,
                    PostCreateView,
                    PostUpdateView,
                    PostDeleteView,
                    BookIssueView,
                    BookReturnView)

urlpatterns = [
    # path('',views.home, name='blog-home'),
    path('',PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/',PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/',PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/',PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/',PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/issue/',BookIssueView.as_view(), name='book-issue'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/return/',BookReturnView.as_view(), name='book-return'),
    path('about/',views.about, name='blog-about'),
]
```

Comment: What's wrong with that code?

Comment: Not getting value to filter.
ie, If I click on a book with id=8 then it's not filtering the book with id=8.

I just Updated my code. Please look to it, now it'll be more clear @DanielRoseman

Comment: You're still not describing the problem. What value *is* it getting? What happens? What do you see? What errors do you get? And show your template and URL.

Comment: I don't see any errors, But the book is not issuing when I click Issue Book

Comment: What is the relationship between Post and BookIssue?

Comment: Sir, Now I updated with almost all code and explained it. Now Please look to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id is not in `request.GET`, it is in the `pk` kwarg of the URL.

Also, you don't seem to be doing anything to associate the Post with the BookIssue.

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=self.kwargs["pk"])
post.issued=True
post.save()
response = super().form_valid(form)
form.instance.issued_book.add(post)
return response
```